# getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rightnode' in avl tree

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I am currently learning data structures and I have having an issue in AVL tree

code:

```
from myqueue import Queue   #my custom queue implimented by linked list

class AVL:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.leftnode=self.rightnode=None
        self.height=1

    def LevelOrderTransversal(self):
        if not self:
            return 
        queue=Queue()
        queue.enqueue(self)
        while not (queue.isempty()):
            root=queue.dequeue()
            print(root.data)
            if root.leftnode is not None:
                queue.enqueue(root.leftnode)
            if root.rightnode is not None:
                queue.enqueue(root.rightnode)

def getheight(rootnode):
    if not rootnode:
        return 0
    return rootnode.height

def getbalance(rootnode):
    if not rootnode:
        return 0
    return getheight(rootnode.leftnode)-getheight(rootnode.rightnode)

def leftrotation(disbalancenode):
    rootnode=disbalancenode.rightnode
    disbalancenode.rightnode=disbalancenode.rightnode.leftnode
    rootnode.leftnode=disbalancenode
    disbalancenode.height=1+max(getheight(disbalancenode.leftnode),getheight(disbalancenode.rightnode))
    rootnode.height=1+max(getheight(rootnode.leftnode),getheight(rootnode.rightnode))
    return rootnode

def rightrotation(disbalancenode):
    rootnode=disbalancenode.leftnode
    disbalancenode.leftnode=disbalancenode.leftnode.rightnode
    rootnode.rightnode=disbalancenode
    disbalancenode.height=1+max(getheight(disbalancenode.leftnode),getheight(disbalancenode.rightnode))
    rootnode.height=1+max(getheight(rootnode.leftnode),getheight(rootnode.rightnode))
    return rootnode

def insertnode(rootnode,nodevalue):
    if rootnode.data is None:
        return AVL(nodevalue)
    elif nodevalue<rootnode.data:
        if rootnode.leftnode is None:
            rootnode.leftnode=AVL(nodevalue)
        else:
            insertnode(rootnode.leftnode,nodevalue)
    else:
        if rootnode.rightnode is None:
            rootnode.rightnode=AVL(nodevalue)
        else:
            insertnode(rootnode.rightnode,nodevalue)

    rootnode.height=1+max(getheight(rootnode.leftnode),getheight(rootnode.rightnode))
    balance=getbalance(rootnode)
    
    if balance>1 and nodevalue<rootnode.leftnode.data:
        return rightrotation(rootnode)
    if balance>1 and nodevalue>rootnode.leftnode.data:
        rootnode.leftnode=leftrotation(rootnode.leftnode)
        return rightrotation(rootnode)
    if balance<-1 and nodevalue<rootnode.rightnode.data:
        return leftrotation(rootnode)
    if balance<-1 and nodevalue>rootnode.rightnode.data:
        rootnode.rightnode=rightrotation(rootnode.rightnode)
        return leftrotation(rootnode)
    return rootnode



A=AVL(5)
A=insertnode(A,10)
A=insertnode(A,15)
A=insertnode(A,20)
A.LevelOrderTransversal()
```

Since the leftnode is disbalanced so it's raising error in `rightrotation()` method when we try to balance that node

So the error is arising in `insertnode()` method

Error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Anurag Dabas\Desktop\python\avl tree\newavl.py", line 84, in <module>     
    A=insertnode(A,15)
  File "c:\Users\Anurag Dabas\Desktop\python\avl tree\newavl.py", line 76, in insertnode   
    rootnode.rightnode=rightrotation(rootnode.rightnode)
  File "c:\Users\Anurag Dabas\Desktop\python\avl tree\newavl.py", line 45, in rightrotation
    disbalancenode.leftnode=disbalancenode.leftnode.rightnode
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rightnode'
```

I tried debugging but couldn't found anything

Here is my `myqueue.py` file:  [`https://paste-bin.xyz/18851`](https://paste-bin.xyz/18851)

Any help or clue will be appreciated

Thanks

Edit:

currently my tree looks like:

```
  5
   \
   10
     \  
      15
       \
        20
 #as you can see it's clearly unbalance so we need leftrotation since it's RR condition
```

so after doing left rotation result looks like:

```
    10
   /  \  
  5    15
        \
         20
```

Comment: You're trying to access `disbalancenode.leftnode.rightnode`, however `disbalancenode.leftnode` is `None`.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes Sir so how to fix that(I guess the logic for rotation is correct and the condition for calling rotation is also correct)

Comment: How to fix it is _don't do that_!  If disbalancenode.leftnode is None, don't try to access disbalancenode.leftnode.rightnode.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you sir I changed `disbalancenode.leftnode.rightnode` to `rootnode.leftnode` and it is working :)

Comment: The example you added at the bottom of your question is not realistic: you could never reach that tree to begin with, as it would have rotated even before getting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually several reasons why you get this error:

- The balance factor is calculated in the opposite sense than it is commonly done: your balance factor will be positive when the tree has a higher left subtree, and negative when it has a higher right subtree. This is confusing to me.
- Possibly you had the same confusion, because the comparison operators in the multiple `if` conditions (like: `nodevalue<rootnode.leftnode.data`) are in the wrong sense, and so your code ended up doing the wrong rotation, leading to the exception.
- When you do a double rotation, then the rotations should be opposite in direction. In one case you have two consecutive `leftrotation` calls. That is wrong.

So without changing the balance calculation, you would correct it with:

```
    rootnode.height=1+max(getheight(rootnode.leftnode),getheight(rootnode.rightnode))
    balance=getbalance(rootnode)
    if balance>1 and nodevalue<rootnode.leftnode.data:
        return rightrotation(rootnode)
    if balance>1 and nodevalue>rootnode.leftnode.data:
        rootnode.leftnode=leftrotation(rootnode.leftnode)
        return rightrotation(rootnode)  # <-- corrected
    if balance<-1 and nodevalue>rootnode.rightnode.data:
        return leftrotation(rootnode)
    if balance<-1 and nodevalue<rootnode.rightnode.data:
        rootnode.rightnode=rightrotation(rootnode.rightnode)
        return leftrotation(rootnode)
    return rootnode
```

Comment: Thanks sir for the answer like you mentioned I tried calling `leftrotation()` but it is still throwing error and also sir how to protect both function against de referencing :(

Comment: Did you draw on paper the process? Can you show your analysis? We expect some effort from your side too. Make sure that you perform the correct rotations in *all* scenarios. Because this was not the only one that was wrong.

Comment: Furthermore your code has many places where attributes of `leftnode` or `rightnode` are accessed without making sure those are not `None`.

Comment: Looking more at your code, I see you have a balance calculation that is opposite to how it is commonly done. Updated my answer.

Comment: And there was also an error with a double rotation. You should really debug your code step by step. You are now using us as your debugger, but these are things you can do yourself. Draw on paper, step through the code execution, line by line, verify  variables, ...Etc

Comment: Sir I tried but can't able to figure out correct condition to handle such situation also Sir I tried the code that you provided but then it occurs in infinite loop..kindly help sir :(

Comment: Please provide the driver code (with the tree being built) that gives the wrong results. I used the code in the question, and just altered this block of code in my answer, and it works.

Comment: Sir I got my answer...thnx for your time and efforts :) also sir can you pls make edit to your answer and change it to https://paste-bin.xyz/19116 so that I can accept it :)

Comment: I don't see why that change is relevant. It is equivalent to what it was (`rootnode` and `disbalancenode.rightnode` are the same node reference). If you want to avoid code repetition there is a *lot* you could improve on, but that is not the scope of your question.

Comment: Sir I changed `disbalancenode.leftnode.rightnode` to `rootnode.leftnode` inside the `leftrotation()` function and it is working

Comment: There is no `disbalancenode.leftnode.rightnode` in `leftrotation`. If you meant `disbalancenode.rightnode.leftnode`, then this change doesn't change anything to the logic. Like I said, it is the same reference as `rootnode.leftnode`. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes Sir I got it :) and thanks for helping me again :)

Comment: sir I taked help from this article https://favtutor.com/blogs/avl-tree-python

Comment: Had a quick look, but it is not such a good article. Often the balance factor has the wrong sign in the images.  This is the case for instance with the images below "Single RR(Right Right) Rotation", below "LR(Left-Right) Rotation", and below "RL (Right-Left) Rotation". I would look for better resources. Wikipedia's article is fine.